# Exception inflating navigation graph

Tags: android, android-navigation-graph

I just updated Android Studio to v3.5 and my project stopped to run, giving me the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mcampana.turle/com.mcampana.turle.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.mcampana.turle:navigation/nav_graph line 23
    at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:90)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:436)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:418)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:236)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2655)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1278)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1581)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:104)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.mcampana.turle.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
```

As far as I understand, Android rises this exception because it is not able to inflate the Navigation Graph in my MainActivity...but I haven't changed anything since the last run!

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@id/navigation_restaurants"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.RestaurantsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_restaurants"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_restaurants" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_to_map"
        app:destination="@id/mapFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fragment_open_enter"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fragment_fade_enter" />

    <argument
        android:name="restaurant"
        android:defaultValue="null"
        app:argType="com.mcampana.turle.model.Restaurant" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@id/navigation_profile"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_login"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_userprofile"
        app:destination="@id/userProfileFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.RegisterFragment"
    android:label="fragment_register"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.LoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_register"
        app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/userProfileFragment"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.UserProfileFragment"
    android:label="fragment_user_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_profile" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_qrfragment"
        app:destination="@id/QRCodeFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/QRCodeFragment"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.QRCodeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_qrcode"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_qrcode" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:name="com.mcampana.turle.MapFragment"
    android:label="fragment_map"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_map_to_restaurant"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_restaurants" />
</fragment>

</navigation>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.mcampana.turle:navigation/nav_graph` line 23 add nav_graph xml file too.

Comment: @SohailZahid added, sorry

Comment: I also have similar error: Exception inflating com.ischn.hr.fptjobs:navigation/nav_graph line 4

Comment: any luck on this issue?

Comment: @user2905416 such an error is also thrown if your argument type is not Parcelable or Serializable, for example.

Comment: @MattiaCampana there would be a longer stack trace that explains the root cause behind this runtime exception

Answer (score 2):

For others who faced with this issue, I solved it by implementing Serializable in my model class.

```
public class Model implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```